# How can we access private blockchain from another network?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, dapps, bootnodes

I have private Ethereum network running on my local network with two sealer node and one bootnode. I have deployed the private blockchain and configured it using geth. Now I want to create another node from another network to connect to that private blockchain deployed. How can I do that if I want to access a contract from the new node?

Comment: It two different networks, you cant reach one from another.

Comment: @Зелёный can't the new node be created using the external Ip of the bootnode?

Comment: It's confusing when you say "another network". In most blockchain ecosystem, "another network" would refer to the difference between the Ethereum mainnet and another network like Ropsten. These 2 networks can't simply be connected. I'm assuming in your original post that you mean the literal definition of network, as in connecting a node over the internet to your local network?

Comment: @flygoing I meant connecting a new node that belongs to a different local network to my private blockchain like connecting my pc at home to another pc in the office network

Answer (score 1):

You need to use same genesis file for both private-networks and keep the networkId same.

The from first node type:

> admin.nodeInfo

```
{
  enode: "enode://7622844520524910d2ca3036c7e2e912a441ebfc13fad8d759046abe1a9d664cf5e09c5edb765ee0cfe64d64645f1b1b16cc6b2d1c4ec557e5eb96f09335f066@[::]:30312",
  id: "7622844520524910d2ca3036c7e2e912a441ebfc13fad8d759046abe1a9d664cf5e09c5edb765ee0cfe64d64645f1b1b16cc6b2d1c4ec557e5eb96f09335f066",
  ip: "::",
  listenAddr: "[::]:30312",
  name: "Geth/PrivateChain1/v1.8.7-stable-66432f38/linux-amd64/go1.10",
  ports: {
    discovery: 30312,
    listener: 30312
  },
  protocols: {
    eth: {
      config: {
        byzantiumBlock: 0,
        chainId: 193,
        eip150Hash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        eip155Block: 0,
        eip158Block: 0,
        homesteadBlock: 0
      },
      difficulty: 4595264,
      genesis: "0xf6e5dec52d779d6f64e2962f4a60fb5e7072fc6d15935cf7425278b7784016f9",
      head: "0x5a26608afb28b4418c23d808f1df35a8f0baff0f193dcba3d102c25f83d84fe3",
      network: 1902
    }
  }
}
```

From node2:

To add node 1 in peer list of node 2, you need to pass enode info of node1 in addPerr function. Replace [::] with IP of node 1. Use localhost if running both nodes on same machine.

> admin.addPeer("enode://3414c01c19aa75a34f2dbd2f8d0898dc79d6b219ad77f8155abf1a287ce2ba60f14998a3a98c0cf14915eabfdacf914a92b27a01769de18fa2d049dbf4c17694@:30301");

Then you can access smart contracts of node1 from node2.

Comment: PS: I have not tried it though but it should work.

Comment: Here I use a private bootnode for each node discovery on the network1. Is there a need to pass enode info of node1 to node2 of the external network?